# Find all solutions to $a^3 + b^3 = p^4,$ where $p$ is prime, and $a,b$ are natural

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Initially, I tried to break the equation down into $(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$, then break it down into two cases:

I: $(a+b) = p, (a^2-ab+b^2) = p^3$, which yields to a contradiction that $p^2 > p^3.$

II: $(a+b) = p^2, (a^2-ab+b^2) = p^2$, which converts to $p^2(p-1)(p+1) = 3ab.$

However, I can't find any way to use this.

Comment: Hint: $a,b$ must be coprime, and $\gcd(a+b,a^2-ab+b^2)\le 3$. Use these to get an contradiction for large $p$.

Comment: For the "coprime": For $(a,b)$ not coprime case it is trivial... $a=px,b=py$ and $x^3+y^3=p$ so $2\le x+y|x^3+y^3=p$ thus $x+y=p$ and $x=y=1$... That is why I assume in the general case $(a,b)$ coprimea

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track when you render $a+b=p^2,a^2-ab+b^2=p^2$.

You should then plug in

$a^2-ab+b^2=\frac14(a^2+2
ab+b^2)+\frac34(a^2-2ab+b^2)$

$=\frac14(a+b)^2+\frac34(a-b)^2.$

Then conclude that with $a+b=p^2,a^2-ab+b^2=p^2$, you must have

$p^2\ge\frac14p^4.$

From this $p\le2$, thereby limiting your solution candidates.

Comment: For $(a,b)$ not coprime case it is trivial... $a=px,b=py$ and $x^3+y^3=p$ so $2\le x+y|x^3+y^3=p$ thus $x+y=p$ and $x=y=1$... That is why I assume in the general case $(a,b)$ coprimea

Answer (score 2):

Hint: It is easy to see $p = 3$ has no solutions. For $p \ne 3$, we have
$$
ab = p^2\left[\frac{(p-1)(p+1)}{3}\right].
$$
The quantity in brackets is an integer (why?), so what can we conclude from this about the divisibility of $a$ and $b$ by $p$? Can you take it from here?

> Either $p$ divides both $a$ and $b$, or $p^2$ divides one of them (say $a$). The second case has no solutions, because $a^3 > p^6 > p^4$. The first case follows as in JetfiRex's comment, and gives $a = b = p = 2$.